# How to select files from hard drive in osx with selenium

Tags: macos, selenium

I have specific scenario that i am get into website and after several clicks via `selenium` i need to select file to upload from my hard drive, so after the window is open i need to select my file and this i cannot do with `selenium`, any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

This depends on how the file upload on the web page is implemented.

This guide could help you though: https://saucelabs.com/resources/articles/selenium-file-upload